# Importing pybind11 module results in 'symbol not found in flat namespace' error. How can I resolve this?

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

"symbol not found in flat namespace" error when importing pybind11 module

I wrote a few classes in C++ that I want to package using pybind11. I haven't worked with pybind11 until now so I watched a tutorial of a basic example and followed all the steps. Everything builds fine and the package installs on a Python 3.8.9 virtual environment, but when I try to import I get:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/$USER/dictionary/py_test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MODULE.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PyCMethod_New'
```

I looked at the other answers that are related to my issue and none helped me as their CMake files weren't displayed. This is where I believe my issue is, but I am not entirely sure. I have spent considerable time trying to fix this, but my knowledge of CMake and build systems is lacking.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4...3.18)
SET (CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang")
set (PYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION "3.8")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -fPIC")
project(MODULE)
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64")

include_directories("/Users/$USER/dictionary/pybind11/include",
                    "/Users/$USER/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.9.12-hdfd78df_0/include/python3.9",
                    "/Users/$USER/dictionary/includes")

add_library(LIB_NAME STATIC src/BINDER_FILE.cpp)
set_target_properties(LIB_NAME PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(MODULE src/BINDER_FILE.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MODULE PRIVATE LIB_NAME)
```

I ran the following in my terminal:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make LIB_NAME
make MODULE
cd ../
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

I have an M1 Macbook.

Answer (score 2):

One reason you might be getting that error is because the python module you have built cannot find any of the Python symbols it needs. You need to link against the python library.

On MacOS, python comes installed as a framework, so you only need to add two linker flags when compiling. Something like this should work:

```
-F/Library/Frameworks -framework Python
```

Additionally, on MacOS (and any unix system like Linux), the python symbols should get resolved by the dynamic linker and picked up by the python executable. So it might be you need to add this to your CMake file:

```
if(APPLE)
  set_target_properties(${MODULE} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-undefined dynamic_lookup")
endif(APPLE)
```

To my understanding, if you are building a standalone python module, then you won't need the second linker flag.

Comment: When adding those linker flags I get `ld: framework not found Python
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. This occurs when building the shared module.

Comment: Oh, I can see that you are using anaconda3 as your python installation. I was expecting the python framework to be in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework as detailed here: https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html
No matter, it just means you need to change the linker flag so that it can find your python installation. I assume anaconda installs as a framework, although I can't find anything verifying that:
`-F/Users/$USER/opt/anaconda3/pkgs`

Comment: Unfortunately the error still remains. Do you think it is possible that the issue is with my setup.py? I used this file: https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/master/setup.py, except I changed the extension module name.

Comment: I'm not sure; my knowledge is mainly in C++/PyBind11. I'm weaker with python, so I cannot say for sure. Your error message strongly suggests it is a linker issue, since the module cannot resolve those symbols. As a hack, try to find this file: `libpython3.9.dylib`. The aforementioned shared library contains the symbol `_PyCMethod_New`. Then add this flag: `-L/path/to/libpython3.9.dylib -lpython`. (Or maybe `-lpython3.9`) Thats all I can suggest without testing on your specific machine

Comment: I'm having the same issue, interested to hear if you've found a solution!